# Using if statement in where clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

With if in a where statement I'm trying to get all rows where datetime is larger then NOW(), but if type = 'economy', i would like to constraint it to only show if datediff between datetime and NOW() is larger than 14 days.

**Something like:**

```
Select type,date(datetime) as date
from tbl1
where datetime > NOW()
IF(type = 'economy') && datediff(datetime,NOW()) > 14
order by datetime desc
```

I've tried with case when also, but can't figure it out...

Comment: Are your actual field names called that (i.e. datetime)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just separate the criteria into 2 different comparisons:

```
select type,date(datetime) as date 
from tbl1 
where (datetime > NOW() AND type <> 'economy') OR
      (datediff(datetime, NOW()) > 14 AND type = 'economy')
order by datetime desc
```

(Not checked for syntax errors, but the idea should be right...)

Comment: Yes, this worked :) Thanks to the two later answers - they are somewhat the same, so I'll check this one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE ((type <> 'economy') AND (datetime > now)) OR ((type = 'economy') AND (datediff(datetime,NOW()) > 14)
```

'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT type, date(datetime) AS date 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE ( type <> 'economy' AND datetime > NOW() ) 
    OR ( type = 'economy' AND datediff(datetime, NOW()) > 14 )
```

Comment: -1, You will need to check for (type <> 'economy') in the first part of the where statement.

Comment: Right on ... knew I forgot something.  Adjusted.